# PHP - include files from array only if all exist in directory

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, include

I'm trying to create a script for including (through require_once) multiple files, but I'm expecting from it following behavior:

- all file names of required files are defined as values in array
- script check if all files from array exist in given directory
- if yes, require them and continue (only if each of them exist)
- if no, terminate script and show error message (if any file is missing)

### **UPDATE**

After taking a closer look at my original script I found why it didn't work. Second IF statement ($countMissing == 0) was inside FOR loop and it produced empty arrays for files which were found. Taking that IF statement out of the loop sorted the problem.

**WORKING VERSION** (with few tiny modifications):

```
// Array with required file names
$files = array('some_file', 'other_file', 'another_file');
// Count how many files is in the array
$count = count($files);
// Eampty array for catching missing files
$missingFiles = array();

for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    // If filename is in the array and file exist in directory...
    if (in_array($files[$i], $files) && file_exists(LIBRARIES . $files[$i] . '.php')) {
        // ...update array value with full path to file
        $files[$i] = LIBRARIES . $files[$i] . '.php';
    } else {
        // Add missing file(s) to array
        $missingFiles[] = LIBRARIES . $files[$i] . '.php';      
    }
}

// Count errors
$countMissing = count($missingFiles);
// If there was no missing files...
if ($countMissing == 0) {
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        // ...include all files
        require_once ($file);
    }
} else {
    // ...otherwise show error message with names of missing files
    echo "File(s): " . implode(", ", $missingFiles) . " wasn't found.";
}
```

If this thread won't be deleted I hope it will help somebody.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$files = array(
    'some_file', 
    'other_file', 
    'another_file',
);

// create full paths
$files = array_map(function ($file) {
    return ROOT_DIR . $file . '.php')
}, $files);

// find missing files
$missing = array_filter($files, function ($file) {
    return !file_exists($file);
});

if (0 === count($missing)) {
    array_walk($files, function ($file) {
        require_once $file;
   });
} else {
    array_walk($missing, function ($file) {
        echo "File: " . $file " wasn't found.";
    });
}
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this, prevent loop inside the loop.

```
for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    // If filename is in the array but file not exist in directory...
    if (in_array($files[$i], $files) && !file_exists(ROOT_DIR . $files[$i] . '.php')) {
        // ...add name of missing file to error array
        $errors[] = $files[$i];
    }
    else{

        require_once (ROOT_DIR . $file[$i] . '.php');

    }
  }
```

Comment: I started with script like that but it didn't work, that's why I tried to add another loop as error check. It acting like it's ignoring IF and performing only ELSE than breaking the rest of scripts on the page because some required files are missing.

Answer (score -1):

The code from localheinz and jp might be fine, but I wouldn't code things like that because it makes things complicated. Assuming you don't want a list of missing files (which would be slightly different) I'd do it like this:

```
$filesOK=true;
foreach($files as $file)
{
   $path = ROOT_DIR . $file . ".php";

   if(!file_exists($path )) 
   {
       $filesOK=false; // we have a MIA
       break;          // quit the loop, one failure is enough 
   }
}

if($filesOK)
   foreach($files as $file)
      require_once($file);
else
   echo "We have a problem";
```

For me this is much easier to see at a glance. Easier to debug, and the CPU is going to do the same job one way or anther. Probably not much difference in execution speed - if that even mattered.

If you need the list of missing files, then:

```
$filesOK=true;
foreach($files as $file)
{
   $path = ROOT_DIR . $file . ".php";

   if(!file_exists($path)) // assume each file is given with proper path
   {
       $filesOK=false; // we have a MIA
       $mia[]=$path;   // or $file if you just want the name
   }
}

if($filesOK)
   foreach($files as $file)
      require_once($file);
else
{
   if(is_array(@$mia))         // I always make sure foreach is protected
     foreach($mia as $badfile) // even if it seems obvious that its ok 
        echo "Missing in action: $badfile<br>";
}
```